# Derivative of quadratic expression with weighted sum of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, optimization

I was looking for a short representation of the derivative w.r.t $a,b,c,\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ of the following expression:

$\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{2}
\left
\lVert
\left(
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha\\
\beta\\
\gamma
\end{pmatrix}^T
\otimes 
I_{m\times m}
\right)
\begin{pmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} \\
A_{21} & A_{22} & A_{23} \\
A_{31} & A_{32} & A_{33} 
\end{pmatrix}
\left(
\begin{pmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{pmatrix}
\otimes
I_{n\times n}
\right)x-b\right\rVert^2_2$

Here, $A_{ij}$ are matrices of dimension $m\times n$ and $a,b,c,\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are scalars, $x$ and $b$ are vectors. I thus mean a weighted sum of matrices as shown below.

$
D=
\alpha(aA_{11}+bA_{12}+cA_{13})+
\beta(aA_{21}+bA_{22}+cA_{23})+
\gamma(aA_{31}+bA_{32}+cA_{33})
$

I was wondering if one can write the derivative with respect to these weight vectors in a short and easy to read form, i.e. take

$d=\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}$

$\delta=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\\\gamma\end{pmatrix}$

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the answer.

Lets say:

$D=
\left(
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha\\
\beta\\
\gamma
\end{pmatrix}^T
\otimes 
I_{m\times m}
\right)
\begin{pmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} \\
A_{21} & A_{22} & A_{23} \\
A_{31} & A_{32} & A_{33} 
\end{pmatrix}
\left(
\begin{pmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{pmatrix}
\otimes
I_{n\times n}
\right)$

The derivative of $Dx$ w.r.t. $\delta$ is

$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial Dx}{\partial \delta_i} =&
\begin{pmatrix}
A_{i1} & A_{i2} & A_{i3} 
\end{pmatrix}
\left(d\otimes I_{n\times n}\right)x\\
=& 
\begin{pmatrix}
A_{i1}x & A_{i2}x & A_{i3}x 
\end{pmatrix}d\\
=& M_{ij}d\\
\frac{\partial Dx}{\partial \delta} =& 
\begin{pmatrix}
M_{1j}&M_{2j}&M_{3j}
\end{pmatrix}
\left(I_{3\times 3}\otimes d\right)\\
\end{align}\\
$

The derivative of $\Phi$ w.r.t. $\delta$ is thus

$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \delta} =&
\left(I_{3\times 3}\otimes d^T\right)
\begin{pmatrix}
M_{1j}^T\\M_{2j}^T\\M_{3j}^T
\end{pmatrix}
\left[
\left(
\left(I_{3\times 3}\otimes d^T\right)
\begin{pmatrix}
M_{1j}^T\\M_{2j}^T\\M_{3j}^T
\end{pmatrix}
\right)^T\delta-b
\right]\\
=&
M_\delta^T\left(M_\delta\delta-b\right)
\end{align}$

The derivative w.r.t to $d$ just involves swapping the indices

$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial d} =&
\left(I_{3\times 3}\otimes \delta^T\right)
\begin{pmatrix}
M_{i1}^T\\M_{i2}^T\\M_{i3}^T
\end{pmatrix}
\left[
\left(
\left(I_{3\times 3}\otimes \delta^T\right)
\begin{pmatrix}
M_{i1}^T\\M_{i2}^T\\M_{i3}^T
\end{pmatrix}
\right)^Td-b
\right]\\
=&
M_d^T\left(M_d^{}d-b\right)
\end{align}$

And, for completeness, the derivative w.r.t $x$

$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x} =&
D^T(Dx-b)
\end{align}$